# Is it possible to override pure virtual functions to templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I do not know if this is even possible :
Lets say I have an interface which defines :

```
virtual void func()=0;
```

is it possible that in the concrete class I override it like the following :

```
template <std::size_t  number> 
void func(){ /* do something with number... */ }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I meant : 
template <typename T>
 void func() { //do something with T}

Comment: If the entire class containing the override is made templated, then you can override and do stuff with `number`, so long as you're okay having the entire class being templated.

Answer (score 6):

> is it possible that in the concrete class I override it like the following :

No, that won't work.

Think of this case.

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void func()=0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
   template <std::size_t  number> 
   void func(){}
};
```

and

```
Base* b = new Derived;
b->func(); // Which of the Derived::func() should that resolve to at run time?
           // Derived::func<0>()?
           // Derived::func<10>()?
           // ...
```

That does not make conceptual sense at all.

Comment: You mean `b->func( )` ?

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, indeed.

Comment: Is it intended that you switch from a `size_t` template value in your class definition to a `typename` in the comments about calling the function?

Comment: Also there is a spelling error in the comments ... `func<doule>`

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName, That needed to be a value instead of a type.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Function templates never override a virtual function, pure or otherwise.